# Can we stack a 2 columns in a single column in basic column Highchart and let the other columns let it be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Here in this example want to stack **Tokyo** and **New York** column into one stacked column and let London and Berlin columns as be.

By stacked column I mean a single column with 2 different colors signifying **Tokyo** and **New York**.

Please check this for reference you can find complete code in here:

https://jsfiddle.net/pvswx25j/7/

```
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

}, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

}, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

}, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to set the stacking to 'normal' and stack id for wanted series.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ocby65ej/

```
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    stacking: 'normal',
    stack: 'test'
}, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3],
    stacking: 'normal',
    stack: 'test'
}, ... ]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stack

Comment: Thanks a bunch Sebastian ! Much Appreciated.
Although I have one question -
We can define stacking: 'normal' under plotOptions.column and under each series array element.
So what's the difference between two, is it some kind of Glocal and local logic applies here ?

Comment: Config sets under the `plotOptions` effect globally for each series, config sets for particular series effect only this one. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions